# Is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform')

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm fetching some of the products from the server but I'm getting an error stating as **Another exception was thrown: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
AsyncSnapshot<List>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, type '(dynamic) => ProductsModel' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform')**

```
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
The ParentDataWidget Flexible(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.

Usually, this means that the Flexible widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Flexible widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Flexible is currently placed inside a RepaintBoundary widget.

The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
  RichText ← Text ← FutureBuilder<List<ProductsModel>> ← Container ← Flexible ← RepaintBoundary ← IndexedSemantics ← NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ← AutomaticKeepAlive ← ⋯
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5689:11)
#1      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5705:6)
#2      ParentDataElement._applyParentData.applyParentDataToChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4939:15)
#3      ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4600:14)
#4      ParentDataElement._applyParentData.applyParentDataToChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4942:15)
...
Another exception was thrown: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
AsyncSnapshot<List<ProductsModel>>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, type '(dynamic) => ProductsModel' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform')
```

And this is my ProductModel class

```
class ProductsModel {
  String adid;
  String adsubcatid;
  String aduserid;
  String adname;
  String adcoverimg;
  String addesc;
  String adsPrice;
  String adsLocation;
  String createdDate;
  String userName;
  String images;

  ProductsModel(
      {this.adid,
        this.adsubcatid,
        this.aduserid,
        this.adname,
        this.adcoverimg,
        this.addesc,
        this.adsPrice,
        this.adsLocation,
        this.createdDate,
        this.userName,
        this.images});

  factory ProductsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ProductsModel(
      adid: json['adid'],
      adsubcatid: json['adsubcatid'],
      aduserid: json['aduserid'],
      adname: json['adname'],
      adcoverimg: json['adcoverimg'],
      addesc: json['addesc'],
      adsPrice: json['ads_price'],
      adsLocation: json['ads_location'],
      createdDate: json['created_date'],
      userName: json['user_name'],
      images: json['images']
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the Main page

```
@override
  void initState() {
    getProducts();
    super.initState();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Home");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Image.asset('assets/images/ic_logo.png'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: FlatButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
              label: Text('Mysuru, India'),
              textColor: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: SizedBox(
              child: _search(),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: SizedBox(
              child: HorizontalCategories(),
            ),
          ),
          SliverGrid(
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              childAspectRatio: 0.7,
            ),
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) => _products(context)),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

 Widget _products(BuildContext context) {
    print("Inside products");
    return Flexible(
      child: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<ProductsModel>>(
          future: _fetchProducts(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print("Has data");
              List<ProductsModel> data = snapshot.data;
              return _productsList(data);
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              print("Error");
              print(snapshot.hasError);
              print(snapshot);
              return Text('${snapshot.hasError}');
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<List<ProductsModel>> _fetchProducts() async {
    String productsUrl = Constant.productsUrl;
    Map<String, String> headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};

    final response = await http.get(productsUrl, headers: headers);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      print(jsonResponse);
      return jsonResponse
          .map((products) => new ProductsModel.fromJson(products))
          .toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load Categories from API');
    }
  }
```

And this is the JsonResponse

```
{
    "status": true,
    "record": [
        {
            "adid": "1",
            "adsubcatid": "1",
            "aduserid": "2",
            "adname": "Ads",
            "adcoverimg": "Royal Enfield Classic 350 Images Classic 350 Photos & 360 View_files.JPG",
            "addesc": "vsv dsv  sd fds fd fdsf dsf s fds fdssfdf c sfdf sd",
            "ads_price": "3000",
            "ads_location": "mysore",
            "created_date": "06/10/2020",
            "user_name": "sunil",
            "images": "{'adsimg_img':'2.JPG'},{'adsimg_img':'3.JPG'},{'adsimg_img':'4.JPG'}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please add `jsonResponse`? Sample response.

Comment: `jsonResponse` is not an iterable (list) so `map` can't be called on it.

Comment: Flexible widgets can only have flex widgets (Row or Column) as parents. Try removing the Flexible Widget in the _products method.

Comment: Even if I'm removing the Flexible its giving me an error in Futurebuilder

Answer (score 1):

you want to get the list `record` is what you should target!

```
var data = jsonResponse['record'];
```

Full api call

```
  Future<List<ProductsModel>> _fetchProducts() async {
    String productsUrl = Constant.productsUrl;
    Map<String, String> headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};

    final response = await http.get(productsUrl, headers: headers);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      var data = jsonResponse['record'];
      return data
          .map((products) => new ProductsModel.fromJson(products))
          .toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load Categories from API');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The root of your "jsonResponse" is not a list.

Try something like this:

```
var jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
var objRoot = ObjRoot.fromJson(jsonResponse);
var products = objRoot.record.map((obj) => ProductsModel.fromJson(obj)).toList();
return products;
```

Answer (score 0):

Map function can not be applied to jsonResponse.

```
return jsonResponse
          .map((products) => new ProductsModel.fromJson(products))
          .toList();
```

`JsonResponse` contains records in `record` field that should be mapped to `ProductsModel`.

```
return jsonResponse
          .record
          .map((products) => new ProductsModel.fromJson(products))
          .toList();
```